# trying to use .then() in my server side script which uses node js but i get an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

When i tried using .then() after an asynchronous function, I get the following error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

I am trying to use it in a server side application. When the client side requests for credential validation, my application checks whether the data received exists in the Mongo DB.

```
app.post('/checkUserDetails',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("request: ",req.body);

        UserDetail.findOne({username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password}).then(function(result,done){
            if(result==undefined){
                res.send({"status": "succesfull, Welcome Admin !!!"});
                done();
            }
            else{
                res.send({"status": "Password or id wrong"});
                done();
            }
        });

});
```